# Response.Redirect and javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using javascript to make call to server. The javascript code is following,

```
function cs() {
    alert("");

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "lp.aspx?pb=true", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And my server code is following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["pb"] != null) 
    {
        Response.Redirect("main.aspx");
    }
}
```

The problem is my Response.Redirect is not working with my ajax call. Why is that?

Comment: What do you want to do with `Response.Redirect("main.aspx");` code? Because you are requesting for `lp.aspx` Use `main.aspx` instead of `lp.aspx`.

Comment: at click of an element the user will be redirected to main.aspx. the element click is wired to the cs() javascript function (look at the q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple you can not use response on ur ajax call. use

```
window.location
```

Comment: Pity you didn't give the accepted answer to Arindram, as he told you that 2 days ago

Answer (score 1):

You can not redirect on ajax call, because, it expects some return value from the invoked page. And if that page itself redirects, it has no way to tell calling function  to redirect, as it simply expects some return value in `success` callback.

So to solve this, you can return a `param` lets say `{ redirect: true }` if condition satisfied. And on `success` callback , if `redirect` is true, then redirect using JS - `window.location.href="required"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that redirect doesn't work because the Response for the page with the javascript is closed before the AJAX call is even made.

Instead of using Response.Redirect you could send back a string containing the url and in your script use location.href to redirect.